# What does "more often" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The next day Mr. Martin followed his routine, as usual. **He polished his glasses more often** and once sharpened an already sharp pencil, but not even Miss Paird noticed.

Does more often mean "more than usual"?

Comment: Because the previous sentence mentions "as usual", this "more often" would mean "more often than usual".

Comment: Although I would have written it as: *The next day Mr. Martin **tried to follow** his routine as usual...* Because clearly he did not manage to duplicate his routine exactly.

Comment: @Jim I agree that he didn't duplicate it exactly. I think that "tried to follow" indicates a greater degree of failure than just excess glasses-polishing and unnecessary pencil-sharpening though. Maybe he "mostly" followed his routine or maybe it was "almost as usual".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say like this:

> He polished his glasses more often than he usually does

OR

> He polished his glasses more frequently than he usually does

Comment: The end of each sentence should read "usually does", not "do usually".

Answer (score 1):

"More often" refers to an action that is done generally often *already* and now that frequency is being increased. The passage is indicating an exaggerated behavior that he is carrying out which emphasizes his state of mind: anxiety or stress.

Answer (score -1):

- He polished his glasses **more often** and once sharpened an already sharp pencil, but not even Miss Paird noticed..

This means that he did it "**more often that usual**"; usually he polished them less often.